# Trouble with simple array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single object in an array like this:

I'm getting some data like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'myphp.php'
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data) //gives [{"userId":"xyz1234"}]
           console.log(data.userId) // undefined
        }
    });
```

What am I missing here? Why can't I get `userId` from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said, you have an *array* with one object, you need to use the index:

```
 console.log(data[0].userId);
```

Comment: So many answers came in that i accidentally clicked on edit on your post instead of his comment -_-

Comment: My screen moved down because of this incoming answer just as i clicked "edit" but i didn't pay attention :-/

Answer (score 5):

Since you `data` is ***array-of-object***, so You need to do:-

```
console.log(data[0].userId);
```

Note:- if `data` array contains more-objects (i.e ***array-of-objects***) then you need to do a `each()` loop like below:-

```
$.each(data,function(index,value){
  console.log(value.userId);
});
```

Example:-

```js
var data = [{userId: 1},{userId: 2},{userId: 3},{userId: 4}];

$.each(data,function(index,value){
  console.log(value.userId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to get the first array item like this:

```
console.log(data[0].userId)
```

In the end you could do something like this:

```js
let data = [{userId: 1},{userId: 112},{userId: 133},{userId: 341}]

for(let item of data) {
    console.log(item.userId)
}
```